# Create graph in ASP based on the values from database

Tags: asp-classic, charts

does anyone know how to create a bar/pie graph based on the value from database in ASP? For example, i would to create a graph based on the number of people who went for vacation in certain state..I would like to retrieve the value directly from database..need help..thanks..

Comment: Classic ASP, or ASP.NET?

Comment: So you have other constraints?  Is this a public web site or is it an intranet?  Are you only interested in something which can be acheived with with free/open source products or would you look at a commercial product?

Answer (score 5):

You could check out [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of great javascript libraries which can take datasets and convert them into graphs.

- [canvasgraph](http://www.liquidx.net/canvasgraphjs/)
- [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)

are two of the big ones.  The plus of javascript is that the processing is done client side and you don't have to send over images, just JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo also works well, though documentation is a little scarce.

Microsoft's Office Web components (OWC11) also works on the server side, and it's fairly easy to use.

Third option is to use plain old HTML.  Works well sometimes if you want a simple chart, like a horizontal bar chart.  You can use a table, with div / span tags set to correct widths ad colors for the bars.  Free, easy and requires no plugins of any kind to work.